# Linux device tree, multiple devices on same irq

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, device-tree

I have an embedded system on which I can connect two different touch screen controllers (ft5x06 or sitronix) depending on my provider.

I would like to have only one software.

I put the two controllers in the device tree, and the probe mechanism will do the job!

```
        i2c1: i2c@f0018000 {              
            edt-ft5x06@38 {
                compatible = "edt,edt-ft5x06";
                reg = <0x38>;
                pinctrl-names = "default";
                pinctrl-0 = <&pinctrl_ft5x06>;
                interrupt-parent = <&pioE>;
                interrupts = <7 0>;
                reset-gpios = <&pioE 6 GPIO_ACTIVE_LOW>;
            };
            sitronix_ts@55 {
                compatible = "sitronix,ST1633";
                reg = <0x55>;
                pinctrl-names = "default";
                pinctrl-0 = <&pinctrl_st1633>;
                interrupt-parent = <&pioE>;
                interrupts = <7 0>;
                reset-gpios = <&pioE 6 GPIO_ACTIVE_LOW>;
            };
        };
```

It works except for the interrupt:
the ft5x06 get the IRQ 7 assigned, but the sitronix doesn't get it :(
(the probe function does not request the irq if the component is not detected on I2C bus, so the IRQ keep free for the other one).

Is there something to share this interrupt, or should I do it otherway?

Comment: Second parameter to interrupts is flags. You need to enable `IRQF_SHARED` on both devices. Be prepared that not all drivers are designed for that.

Comment: IMHO, you need to have two different device tree files depending upon your provider; and put a single I2C device node on both device trees. That's the whole point behind device trees - store hardware specific details in it, and pass it to kernel so that no change in kernel required.

Comment: Thanks for the responses!
@0andriy: IRQF_SHARED gave me "syntax error" at compilation (linux kernel 3.10)

Comment: @vtha: creating 2 different dtb is the easy solution but how can we manager custom hardware expension bus with custom plug and play board for example (ISA old style)? Should I drop the device tree and go back to board/platform description?

Comment: @Yvan, I think you need to check the interrupt controller on your device and its the device tree binding to understand if it supports passing flags (IRQF_SHARED). I quickly checked on kernel 4.4.X and from "pioE" as interrupt parent, it looked like atmel based AIC and does not support passing IRQF_SHARED flag. I am not sure though.

Comment: @Yvan, there are device tree overlays. They allow you to attach or detach hardware on running system.